# Как сделать анимированный фон в Python

Tags: python, arcade

Я делаю простенькую игру в python с использованием библиотеки arcade, где нужно за машину уклоняться от препятствий, и мне нужно сделать анимированный фон(дорогу). Какая команда поможет мне это сделать?
Вот код игры:

```
import arcade
import random
class Car(arcade.Sprite):
    def update(self):
        self.center_x+=self.change_x
class Game(arcade.Window):
    def __init__(self,width,height,title):
        super().__init__(width,height,title)        
        self.bg=arcade.load_texture("Road.png")
        self.car=Car("blue_car.png",1)
        self.car.bottom,self.car.center_x=100,270
    def on_draw(self):
        arcade.draw_texture_rectangle(250,400,500,790,self.bg)
        self.car.draw()
    def update(self,delta_time):
        self.car.update()
    def on_key_press(self, key, modifiers):
        if key==arcade.key.LEFT:
            self.car.change_x=-10
        if key==arcade.key.RIGHT:
            self.car.change_x=10
    def on_key_release(self, key, modifiers):
        if key==arcade.key.LEFT:
            self.car.change_x=0
        if key==arcade.key.RIGHT:
            self.car.change_x=0
window=Game(500,800,"Гонки")
window.run()
```

[image: Примерно такой фон мне нужен]

[image: Вот спрайт машины]

Comment: 2 картинка это спрайт автомобиля, а 1 GIF - анимированный фон